# how to scatter plot whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a Pandas dataframe with multiple columns. I like to create a scatter plot where x is the list of all columns, and y is the dataframe index. size of the scatter plot will be the value of each cell. I am having trouble defining it. Dataframe looks like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| 2 | Cell 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

I have tried:

```
df.plot.scatter(x=df.columns, y=df.index, s=lambda x,y)
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

I like to see a chart that show column values as X value, index as Y and size as the value of each cell associated with x and y.

Comment: you need to split the x data into multiple scatter plot, one per features.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to `unstack` to DataFrame and then plot the `scatter` using the column names.

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4], 'C':[5,6], 'D':[7,8]})
sdf = df.unstack().to_frame('size').reset_index()

# not needed, only to apply some color for visibility
j = {'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C':'green', 'D':'black'}
sdf['color'] = sdf['level_0'].map(j)

sdf.plot.scatter(x='level_0', y='level_1', s='size', c='color')
```

#### Output

[image: scatter plot]